# Displaying raw JPEG in html/js

Tags: typescript, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting an image that is in this format:

```
    ����JFIF``��C       

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C          

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222���|"��    
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    
���w!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?�4���)����4�㊎D,>W�}jLsIބ�Y~{鑻a��6�ҙb�'��I�Fj�+��K�R
�dhr=���4�������+R~S���Zq�>�g �5Vղ_��[�y��(,�����Ґ2�$?Z@(��K��I�|Ro��G#қ��K�Ґ��pM7|7w��I���Q@��)��J��jIeo��?�篵Z�����9��8�a����[W%�r��F2E4Es�e��/������]��i�92�Pf���݃yo��O��n���9f�]�;W�=zRt��綃ނ*}Z{ׂ�P!�̤�YEt�s�!���s���zR�EQdP�]\��b�@̫����Q������d��k��t�&�Nk�L��@f�&�>Ê�u�����������`���-�s�/    ���ʪF�p)�f�c�(aLd?p�I�I��7Rr=h��i����2=�2�4���P��'�3擨*����%ߖ�*]��`Q�ڌ�&G�+��5䈹E��Mu2F����E���jϔp�����_�qp����^�V������^�ː���̬b�'l�E/��'漛��
```

Although normally chrome detects the image and shows a preview in the developer panel, it doesn't manage that. The response headers are this which should the the browser that this is an image:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3333
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:2621
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Wed, 05 Oct 2016 12:43:00 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Here is my photo request method in typescript:

```
 private photoHttpRequest(userId: string): Promise<string> {
        const photoRequest: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url: string = "some url" + userId;
        photoRequest.open("GET", url, true);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            photoRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (photoRequest.readyState === 4) {
                    if (photoRequest.status === 200) {
                        resolve(photoRequest.responseText);
                    } else {
                        reject(photoRequest.responseText);
                    }
                }
            };

            photoRequest.send("");
        });
    }
}
```

And after this, i just convert to base64:

```
 let photo: string = await this.photoHttpRequest("1234");
 photo = "data:image/*;base64,"+window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(photo));
```

And pass it in to a `img.src` but that doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: why you use `encodeURIComponent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the response to be a blob

You have two methods

- set xhr's `responseType` to "blob"
- use fetch `fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => console.log(blob))`

Then use `img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)` and do what you want with it

---

Best would be if you didn't need ajax at all since it looks like you are doing a simple GET request

Comment: thanks for the help! Your suggestions helped. Do you know why the way i was doing it didn't work? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Javascript don't handle binaries as string so well, you can get "out of range"  error... so browsers tries to be smart about it and dos parse it and do some modification to it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Receiving_binary_data_in_older_browsers